# How can I vertical center a input with float: left?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="containerDiv">
    <p>Test</p>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.containerDiv 
{
    width:600px;
}

.containerDiv p 
{
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    float: left; 
    width: 500px;
}

.containerDiv input[type='checkbox']
{
    float: right;
    margin: auto 10px;
}
```

Hello,

I have a div with a text (the text can be very long) in a p-tag and a input.
I want vertical center the input right next to the text, but `float: left` and `margin: auto 10px` doesn't work.

Comment: `margin: auto 10px` creates space left and right. Not top and bottom... since there's no real height whatsoever it won't center either way. Have you tried just `margin-top`?

Comment: Use Labels instead of "p" tag...

Comment: Check following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Comment: But the div height is different, dependent how long is the text. When i change margin-top i habe to type in a fixed value?1

Comment: Typo near `<div style="width: 600px;>` : you forgot a close-quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your checkbox in `absolute` position and use `top:50%` minus the checkbox height. So you don't need to `float:right` this element but give it a `right` position. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wXuC/1/

Comment: it wont align for single line p text

Comment: It aligns perfectly if you change `margin-top` to -5px. It's just a matter of testing for the checkbox height behavior. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4wXuC/1/

Comment: Tick my suggestion as "answered" then...  That's the whole point!

Answer (score 0):

For giving margin try `margin: 10px auto;` instead of `margin: auto 10px;`

Answer (score -1):

Use label instead of p and set the line-height of the label to the total height of the input.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <div style="width: 55px;">
<p style="float: left; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px; width: auto;">Test</p>
<input checked="checked" style="float: right; margin: 5px auto;" type="checkbox">
 </div>
```

Comment: ooooops i thought i am helping you

Comment: When the text-length is bigger, there isn't the input vertical center